# Locked by Android manager

Tags: stock-android, android-device-manager

I've used android manager to make my phone ring and Locked it by setting a password wish I never had. But unfortunately when I found the phone I was not able to `deactivate the password` because all option are dammed and the only one showing is password. 
I need to change it again to none.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

if this phone is yours do the following :

- login to you device manager on google website [here](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager)
- click on lock and set a new password this will over-write the old password
- on your phone enter your new pass word

If this phone is not yours contact the phone owner and ask him to do the last steps